# Copying contents in a div on windows resize produces duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery-clone

I'm having a problem with `.clone()` that produces so many duplicates that it crashes my browser.

Here's my example code:

```
<div>
 <div class="mobile-top"></div>
 <div class="date">January 22, 2019 - 13:44</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="mobile-top"></div>
 <div class="date">December 2, 2018 - 3:10</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="mobile-top"></div>
 <div class="date">March 22, 2017 - 1:37</div>
</div>
```

And my JS code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(window).width() < 600) {
  $(".date").clone().appendTo(".mobile-top");
 } else {     
  $(".mobile-top").empty();
 };
}).resize();
```

What I'm trying to do is when a broswer is under 600px, content in the `.date` element gets moved to the `.mobile-top` element. What happens is all three `.date` elements get grouped and moved into `.mobile-top` on each div and continues duplicating the content until the browser crashes.

What I'm trying to do is move the `.date` to `.mobile-top` in each div when screen is under 600px.

Working example of what I've done so far - https://jsfiddle.net/openbayou/f5qwhnp1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do one mistake, that you are cloning. `.date` inside `window.resize` which is continuously cloning and appending again and again here is my code this may help you.

```
var date = $('.date').html(),
    mobileTop = $('.mobile-top');
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $(mobileTop).html(date);
        } else {     
            $(mobileTop).html('');
        };
    }).resize();
```

Comment: wouldn't this replace the html content on every resize event? Don't think it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the element has already been inserted

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.date').forEach(function(el) {
      if (el.parentElement.classList.contains('mobile-top')) {
        return
      }

      var parent = el.parentElement
      var mobileTop = parent.querySelector('.mobile-top')

      mobileTop.appendChild(el)
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="mobile-top"></div>
  <div class="date">January 22, 2019 - 13:44</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="mobile-top"></div>
  <div class="date">December 2, 2018 - 3:10</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="mobile-top"></div>
  <div class="date">March 22, 2017 - 1:37</div>
</div>
```